# SUMPRODUCT and OR Statement is returning double value if both ORs are true?

Tags: excel-formula

I have three columns: Volume, Market 1 and Market 2. Volume has numbers, Market 1 and 2 have either a "Yes" or "No" associated with it. What I want, is a formula that will sum the volumes if either Market 1 or 2 has "yes".

This is what I've tried so far:

=SUMPRODUCT((H10:H17)*((J10:J17="yes")+(K10:K17="yes")))

However, the problem with this formula is that if both Market 1 + 2 = "Yes", it will add that volume twice! What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right that the inner brackets add up to 2 if both columns contain "yes".

You need to use an IF statement to produce a 1 if either or both of the columns contain "yes" as explained [Here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/sum-with-or-criteria.html) for instance.

So your formula would become:-

```
=SUM(H10:H17*IF((J10:J17="yes")+(K10:K17="yes"),1))
```

but it has to be entered as an array formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I have a beginner's follow up question - how would an array affect the spreadsheet? Are there any downsides/benefits to using that array vs a regular function?

Comment: Probably too big a question to be answered here! Personal opinion - many cases where array formulae give a neat solution without affecting performance adversely. See e.g. here for pros and cons http://www.plumsolutions.com.au/articles/should-we-use-array-formulas-everyday-models

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regular function, I would suggest this one:

=SUMPRODUCT(H10:H17*((J10:J17="yes")*(K10:K17="yes")+MOD((J10:J17="yes")+(K10:K17="yes");2)))

(J10:J17="yes")*(K10:K17="yes") - This will produce 1 only when both are yes.
MOD((J10:J17="yes")+(K10:K17="yes");2) - Produces 1 only when one of them is yes.